# Results from "within 7 days" interval not displaying todays results.

Tags: php, mysql

My view_stamp field is formatted like so: `2014-03-02 11:34:32`

My query is as follows:

```
SELECT YearMakeModel, COUNT( id ) AS YMMcount
FROM car_views
WHERE view_stamp < DATE_ADD( NOW( ) , INTERVAL -7 DAY ) 
GROUP BY YearMakeModel
ORDER BY YMMcount DESC 
LIMIT 100
```

The above is supposed to display results from 7 days ago until now. But it is ignoring results from today. It shows everything from 7 days ago until yesterday. No matter the interval.

What am I doing wrong? Using PHP and MySQL.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Should be `>=` instead of `<`

```
WHERE view_stamp >= DATE_ADD( NOW( ) , INTERVAL -7 DAY )
```

Comment: Simple miss. Good to have another set of eyes. Still  learning. Thank you, this worked. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Mike That said, why use `DATE_ADD( NOW(), INTERVAL -7 DAY)` when you could just use `DATE_SUB( NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY )`?

Comment: Because I'm a newbie and don't know the difference. haha. Im guessing your method is more effecient? I will try it now. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Mike It shouldn't be more efficient, but it's easier to read "take the current time and minus it by 7 days" than "take the current time and plus it by minus 7 days". :) It's essentially like saying `2 - 2` or `2 + (-2)`. The latter would just be silly.